# Check if any object of a queryset is present in a m2m field

Tags: python, django

I have the following model :

```
class SalesProject(models.Model):

   
    activeCustomer = models.ManyToManyField(
        'CustomerInformation', through='ProjectActiveCustomer', related_name='activeCustomer')
    inactiveCustomer = models.ManyToManyField(
        'CustomerInformation', through='ProjectInactiveCustomer', related_name='inactiveCustomer')
```

Within my views , i wish to apply the following business logic:

1. When adding new `customerInformation` to `activeCustomer` m2m relation , check if the instance that im adding exists in `inactiveCustomer`
2. If true , Remove the `customerInformation` from the `inactiveCustomer` m2m relation

The data which enters my view comes in the form of a queryset , therefore , the algo that decides this should be able to take in a queryset and check if **any** of the object in this queryset matches the objects in the `inactiveCustomer` m2m relation

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
class SalesProject(models.Model):
    [...]
    def add_customer(self, customer_information):
        if self.inactiveCustomer.filter(id=customer_information.id).exists():
            self.inactiveCustomer.remove(customer_information)
        self.customerInformation.add(customer_information)
```